# ¿Cuándo es correcto usar "en tanto en cuanto"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, expresiones

Hubo una [pregunta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2732/9385) con este párrafo:

> Pasado el tiempo, y relacionado con lo de arriba **en tanto en cuanto** a preguntas de listas, empezamos a observar que la pregunta Resources for learning Spanish podría bien moverse al sitio principal para ejercer de pregunta canónica contra la que marcar como duplicadas las preguntas que consulten por recursos de aprendizaje, algo que más arriba hemos visto que también es una de los motivos de cierre propios del sitio.

Propuse una edición, quitando *en tanto* porque me parecía mejor, pero @walen restauró su texto original, indicando que la frase era correcta.

Todavía no entiendo. La forma en que walen usó la frase se ve diferente que los ejemplos que conozco. ¿Cuándo es correcto usar "en tanto en cuanto"?

Si me lo pueden explicar se lo agradezco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El DPD tiene en su entrada sobre [***tanto -ta***](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=tanto#6) una explicación para entender la frase *en tanto en cuanto*:

> 6. **en tanto en cuanto**. Equivale a *en la medida en que*. Esta locución comenzó a usarse en el lenguaje jurídico a finales del siglo xix y hoy se ha extendido a otros ámbitos: «Una ley tiene fuerza en tanto en cuanto es justa» (PBarba Filosofía [Esp. 1983]); «Esa mujer [...] será dócil en tanto en cuanto nadie la humille» (LTena Renglones [Esp. 1979]).

En la frase que mencionas, *en tanto en cuanto* no podía sustituirse por *en la mediada en que*. Por tanto, no fue correcto su uso y la corrección por *en cuanto* era pertinente.

Answer (score 4):

Sospecho que la cuestión podría ser más complicada de lo que parece. Si el oído no me engaña:

una cosa es '**en** tanto en cuan**t**o' (= 'en la medida en'; 'en proporción de'; pero también homologable, en ciertos casos, a 'bajo la condición de'),

otra '**de** tanto en cuan**d**o' (= 'de vez en cuando'; 'unas sí, otras no'; etc.),

y otra '**en** tanto en cuan**d**o' (= 'siempre y cuando').

Lo digo porque me he encontrado varios casos --escritos-- en los que esas tres locuciones se diría que están como entremezcladas y confundidas en la subconsciencia personal del hablante --lo que, por lo demás, sería comprensible, y no sólo por la similitud fonética de las tres, que también: es que la forma primera parece admitir usos que se acercan peligrosamente a la tercera--, pues usa alguna de ellas donde el sentido parece pedir otra.

Quizá el caso con el que tú te encontrabas tenía algo que ver con esto.